# List of individual results from grouped results

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this SQL script:

```
SELECT distinct 
    A.APNO, B.APUSEINSPKEY, Count(*)
FROM  
    CDR_USE.useappl A, CDR_USE.USEINSP B, 
    CDR_USE.useappldetail C, FIREUSEPERMITS.buildinginfo D, 
    FIREUSEPERMITS.blginfogrd E
WHERE 
    A.APUSEKEY = B.APUSEKEY
    AND a.apusekey = b.apusekey
    AND A.apusekey = C.APUSEKEY
    AND c.apuseappldtlkey = d.apuseappldtlkey
    AND d.buildinginfokey = E.BUILDINGINFOKEY
    AND E.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    A.APNO, B.APUSEINSPKEY
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Which returns this result:

```
*APNO          APUSEINSPKEY  COUNT
*FPBTEN12245     28922        2
*FPBBLD17053     52096        2
*FPBTEN22105     74489        2
*FPBTEN22126     74552        2
*FPBTEN25730     91536        2
```

What code do I need to get a list of the individual records in in each `APNO`? For example, I know there are 2 records in `FPBTEN12245`, but how do I get a list of information for those 2 records listed with information on the rest of the records, all together?

```
FPBBLD33567 125826  2
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use standard `join` syntax.  Second, most databases support window functions, so you can get all the basic results using them:

```
select *
from (SELECT A.*,
             Count(*) over (partition by A.APNO, B.APUSEINSPKEY) as cnt
      FROM  CDR_USE.useappl A join
            CDR_USE.USEINSP B
            on A.APUSEKEY = B.APUSEKEY join
            CDR_USE.useappldetail C
            on A.apusekey = C.APUSEKEY join
            FIREUSEPERMITS.buildinginfo D
            on c.apuseappldtlkey = d.apuseappldtlkey join
            FIREUSEPERMITS.blginfogrd E
            on d.buildinginfokey = E.BUILDINGINFOKEY
      WHERE E.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

I would also recommend using aliases that are abbreviations of your tables, rather than arbitrary letters.  Such a practice makes queries easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the code that I am posting, but I believe it should work

```
SELECT distinct A.APNO, B.APUSEINSPKEY 
FROM  
    CDR_USE.useappl A, 
    CDR_USE.USEINSP B, 
    CDR_USE.useappldetail C, 
    FIREUSEPERMITS.buildinginfo D, 
    FIREUSEPERMITS.blginfogrd E
WHERE A.APUSEKEY = B.APUSEKEY
  AND B.apusekey = C.APUSEKEY
  AND C.apuseappldtlkey = D.apuseappldtlkey
  AND D.buildinginfokey = E.BUILDINGINFOKEY
  AND E.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
  AND (SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM CDR_USE.useappl A2,
            CDR_USE.USEINSP B2 
       WHERE A2.APUSEKEY = B2.APUSEKEY
         AND B2.APUSEKEY=A.APUSEKEY
       ) >  1
```